# d3 how to do concurrent animations?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, concurrency

How do I do concurrent animations on the same group?

For instance I have a group that contains lots of rectangles and has a animation that selects this group and animates it. But I also have a button that selects the SAME group of rectangles and animates the rectangles as well. My problem is that When the first animation occurs and I press the button whilst it is still running, then the button group animation cancels out the previous animation and the previous animation doesn't execute fully.

```
    //Contains lots of rects
    var group = canvas.append("g") 
    //Animation 1 - slowly changes rects width to be wider
    group.selectAll("rect").transition().duration(2000).attr(width, 5000);
    //Animation 2 - slowly changes colour of rect to blue
    //Happens on button click
    group.selectAll("rect").transition().duration(2000).style("fill","blue")
```

Is there a way to make it so that both the animations occur concurrently, so that the second animation does not stop the first animation?

Comment: your group contain a lot of rects but you only append at the same `canvas.append("g")`. Of course it is not working. define your `canvas` or `svg` element with  multi-array to fit the number of rects.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to animate the width of the 'rect', and then animate the fill of the 'g' on button click.

```
d3.selectAll("rect").transition().duration(2000).attr("width", 5000);

d3.select("button").on("click", function() { 
        d3.select("g").transition().duration(2000).style("fill", "blue");
});
```

[View example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandlertee/hAu8a/3/)